# The activities in abaqus/viewer's query>probe values is not recorded in the macro?

Tags: python, macros, abaqus

I am trying to record a macro in abaqus/viewer. The activities in "probe values" function of "query" tool in abaqus/viewer does are not recorded in the macro.

Is there any way to find out what functions called used in "probe values" tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly it doesn't record. But you could use python command to get the output straight from the odb. The syntax would be like follows:

```
session.odbs[name].steps[name].frames[i].fieldOutputs[name].values[i]
```

e.g.

```
session.odbs[session.odbs.keys()[0]].steps['Step-1'].frames[10].fieldOutputs['S'].values[10].maxPrincipal
```

Gives you max Principle stress of element number 11 in step 1 on frame 10.

For more information refer Abaqus Scripting Reference guide. Python commands. Section 34.8

Comment: Thanks, it is good that someone else verified the problem with macro recording and "probe value". I contacted abaqus office and they offered RFE (request for enhancemen), which is already submitte by me. They offered alternative similar function that does the job. The method you offered is what I am using at the moment. Thanks again